# Rails 4 - Mailer deliver_later not doing what I expect, blocks the UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have a rails app in which I have a function that send out quite a few emails. I would like to do it `asynchronously` and I thought that the method `deliver_later` would do that. Currently I have some delay from when the user clicks `submit` until the form is submitted - which is leads to a bad user experience (It is a quite simple form). My implementation looks like this:

```
def create

  respond_to do |format|
    if @competition.save
      [...]
      send_notification_to_team_members
    end
end

def send_notification_to_team_members
  @team.members.each do |member|
    unless member.user.eql?(current_user)
      Mailer.deliver_new_competition_notification(member.user,   @competition).deliver_later
    end
  end
end
```

Currently it takes ~ 4 seconds for the action to be finished. I have also tried:

```
Mailer.deliver_new_competition_notification(member.user,  @competition).deliver_later(wait: 1.minute)
```

Then it takes even longer - I would estimate ~1 minute.

So, am I using `deliver_later` wrongly, or is the method not doing what I expect. In that case, is there another method I can use to improve my performance?

Comment: What activejob backend are you using?

Comment: You should send e-mail asynchronously. If you are using 4.2 you can use ActiveJob, or if not you should use such solutions as Sidekiq or Rescue.

Comment: FYI: [Here](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/getting-started-with-active-job) is good article about using ActiveJob for sending e-mails.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I use `class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base`, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Regarding the comment @maxd made, the same article is also posted [here](https://quickleft.com/blog/getting-started-with-active-job/), where I posted comments on some changes I had to make to get it to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`deliver_later` uses [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#backends) to provide  asynchronous execution.

However ActiveJob does not provide asynchronicity itself - it is a unifying api layer that can be fulfilled by many backends. The default one just runs everything inline it is not async.

To get async usage you need to pick an asynchronous backend. You can configure the backend in your application's config

```
 config.active_job.queue_adapter = ...
```

In general most adapters require a corresponding gem (eg delayed_job, sidekiq, sucker_punch) which may have their own dependencies too (for example sidekiq requires that you use redis.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to install `delayed_job`, with: `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`, and I have followed the installation process here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record. In `application.rb` I've added: `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job`. And I use it like this: `Mailer.deliver_new_competition_notification(member.user, @competition).deliver_later!`. I don't get any errors, but the emails doesn't get delivered - on `localhost:3000`. Have I missed something?

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with `sidekiq` instead. Thought it looked easier to setup. But I ran into some other issues, asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796293/rails-4-2-sidekiq-not-sending-emails-in-development

Comment: Easier than delayed_job?  Worth mentioning that sideqik requires your code (and dependencies) to be thread-safe.  As a happy medium I would recommend resque, as it's way faster than delayed_job, but doesn't require the thread safety of sideqik.