# Rails 4.2 - Sidekiq not sending emails in development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a rails app in which I have a method where I send a lot of emails. I would like to perform this action `asynchronously`. To do it I've tried to use `Sidekiq`, but I can't get it to work properly - it doesn't send any emails.

Sending email worked before, so I'm certain that my email settings is set ut correctly.

In my `gemfile` I have this:

```
gem 'sidekiq'
```

And I have run `bundle install`. I have also install `redis`, followed the instructions on [RailsCasts #366](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

I have started `sidekiq` with the following command: `bundle exec sidekiq`, this resulted in what can be seen in the image below:

[image]

In `application.rb` I have the following:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

And I try to send the emails like this:

```
Mailer.deliver_new_competition_notification(member.user,   @competition).deliver_later!
```

I don't get any errors, but the emails never gets sent.

So, have I missed something?

Comment: Have you included a proc file?

Comment: @sansarp No, I have not. Anthony's answer below was enough to make it work. But I'm curious about Procfiles, could you elaborate on how I can include ad Procfile, what it should contain and why?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to bootup sidekiq with the mailer queue for it to pick up these jobs:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

The Sidekiq Wiki goes over the scenarios in [detail here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#action-mailer).

Answer (score 7):

Also you can modify the config/sidekiq.yml:

```
---
:concurrency: 25
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers
```

And run  `sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`

Comment: running sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml helped me - thanks!